# My applicaiton uses google as the medium to sign in. I am trying the same to do via jmeter script but I am unable to do so.

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

URL I am hitting for sign in is 
https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth/oauthchooseaccount?client_id=314687257509-dfk13dhtelq4o1ti0li7af1akie3ieqm.apps.googleusercontent.com&as=H_7I4EsREAQ2c6c8EejwOw&destination=http%3A%2F%2Fmetacampus-in.appspot.com&approval_state=!ChRUMEJ4bVhFcm5Sb0JxaHgwb1F3bBIfOC1uZGhOTGc1bmdSOEhuU1JuY2dubXJlQXdHdVRCWQ%E2%88%99ANKMe1QAAAAAW1gSB4OWT70lnDr525s7wW0mFo0q0uZ6&oauthgdpr=1&xsrfsig=AHgIfE_kc7fWgnNfGE6nCQu1hzZAma2qcQ&flowName=GeneralOAuthFlow

Comment: Can someone please guide me as how to do. I am new to Jmeter

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to proceed you need to add a proper [Authorization Bearer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750) token via [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager).

There are several ways to obtain the token:

1. Perform login via real web browser using i.e. [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) and extract the token value from the browser
2. Obtain the token from the [developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/)
3. Use [Google OAuth Client Library](https://github.com/google/google-oauth-java-client) from [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) to perform programmatic OAuth login.

See [How to Run Performance Tests on OAuth Secured Apps with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-performance-tests-oauth-secured-apps-jmeter) article for more information on each of the approaches.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply. I am new to Jmeter and have been trying this for first time. Can you guide me step by step for same. Thanks in advance.